# How to detect if a shape hits another in html5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, collision-detection

I'm trying to build a motorbike game in html5 canvas with javascript. 
Right now I have a wheel and a simple gravity which increases the position from the top of the canvas until the wheel hits the bottom of the canvas. When I start the game, the wheel just drops to the bottom of the canvas.

I want to create a curved ground for the wheel to ride on. The problem is that I don't know how to calculate if the wheel hits this ground.

Here is a illustration. I want the wheel to drop until it hits the curved ground, and if I'm moving the wheel, it needs to follow the shape's edge.

[image http://i.minus.com/iFvy1dbnouvy6.png](http://i.minus.com/iFvy1dbnouvy6.png)

I don't want to use any libraries or engines, only javascript and html5. Do you have any ideas or solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the other answer, you can simply have an if statement that says

```
if tire.y < line(tire.x) then tire.y = line(tire.x) - 1
```

the line function can just be an array or some formula that will contain the y value of the line when given any x-value.

Answer (score 0):

In order to detect when the wheel hits the ground, you should have the coordinates of the ground boundary (e.g.: a polyline) and the wheel's ray and center position.

You detect collision by checking that your wheel y coordinate (cener + ray) is below the y coordinate of your polyline at certain *x(s)*. You should segment your polyline in a resonable way, by carefully selecting your endpoints.

Probably there are other ways to accomplish this task, but this is the first which I came out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [**solution**](http://labs.skookum.com/demos/barcampclt_physics/newton/3) which you're looking for Collision Detection (elastic)..
.--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------.
Here's a simple & Good [**tutorial**](http://labs.skookum.com/demos/barcampclt_physics/) for learning physics especially for Game Developers